# 'The' object of composable triples in an internal category

Tags: ct.category-theory, internal-categories

In any category $\mathcal{C}$ with pullbacks, we can define an [internal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category#idea) $\mathscr{C}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ as an object ${\bf Ob}_\mathscr{C}$ of objects and an object ${\bf Hom}_\mathscr{C}$ of arrows, together with arrows
$${\sf dom},{\sf cod}:{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{C}\rightrightarrows{\bf Ob}_\mathscr{C},$$
$$1^\mathscr{C}:{\bf Ob}_\mathscr{C}\to{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{C},$$
$$\circ^\mathscr{C}:{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{C}\times_{{\bf Ob}_\mathscr{C}}{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{C}\to{\bf Hom}_\mathscr{C}$$
satisfying the expected commutative diagrams. Where I'm slightly confused is the associativity axiom, since the 'object of composable triples' can be taken as either one of the two isomorphic options below

[image]

I have no problem showing that they're isomorphic and I understand that pullbacks are usually only defined up to isomorphism anyway, but when expressing the associativity axiom we technically need both to appear in the diagram:

[image]

I haven't seen mention of this on the nlab page linked above, or the introductions to internal categories in Jacob's fibered category theory book, or Borceux/Janelidze's Galois theories book,
which makes me wonder if this is just overly pedantic, but when I went to construct an example of an internal category and prove it satisfied the axioms I ran into this issue in the proof.

> Is there some well-known trick for sweeping things like this under the rug in computations, or do we need to keep track of isomorphisms between internal data for computations to shake out correctly?

Comment: This is usually swept under the rug, yes. Morally this is should be justified by the coherence theorem for monoidal categories but I don’t think it literally applies in this situation.

Comment: Also, this is a particular case of the general situation with monoids in any monoidal category (the one at hand being the monoidal category of endospans of the object of objects).

Comment: Btw, your $\mathscr C$ denotes two different things

Comment: In some treatments of internal categories, an in particular in some of Charles Ehresmann's old versions, the objects of composable pairs and triples is part of the data, so that internal categories are models of finite limit sketches, where the appropriate pullbacks are all given.

Comment: I should add: and the data of the partial composites too! (so: composing the first or last two in a composable triple)

Comment: I don't think any "coherence" (a la Mac Lane) is needed. The objects of composable pairs and triples are just limits of V- and W-shaped diagrams, and similarly for longer strings. Once you've chosen these limits, the isomorphisms are uniquely determined and then you can state associativity in the obvious way.

Comment: Segal-style approaches to encoding associative and commutative structures avoid such problems by encoding objects of composable tuples separately, and then imposing an axiom that says that composable pairs are pullbacks of objects of arrows etc.  The advantage of this is that the definition of an object itself can be concisely stated as a presheaf on Δ or Γ or a similar category, and then one only needs to state Segal's axioms.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov How would these approaches handle actual examples in the wild? For example, given a category $C$ with pullbacks and an arrow $f:X\to Y$ in $C$ we can construct an internal category whose object of objects is $X$, whose object of arrows is  the kernel pair $X\times_YX$ with projections as domain/codomain and the diagonal as identity, and composition as the uniquely induced projection onto the first and fourth components. When I try to show that this internal category is associative, I need the above isomorphism between options for my computations to shake out correctly.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Would defining the object of composable triples as part of the data aviod the problem I'm having in the specific example above?

Comment: @AlecRhea: In Segal's approach, you have a simplicial object D: Δ^op → C  with a property that the induced map D(m+n)→D(m) ⨯_{D(0)} D(n) is an isomorphism.  If we set, as in your example, D(0)=X, D(1)=X⨯_Y X, this guarantees that D(m) will encode composable m-tuples, i.e., is isomorphic to X⨯_Y ⋯ ⨯_Y X.  The associativity problem disappears because you have a single object of composable m-tuples.

Comment: @AlecRhea yes, since it is more of an unbiased definition of composition, where you don't have triples organised as $(f,(g,h))$ vs $((f,g),h)$, but $(f,g,h)$. Also: what Dmitri said. Ehresmann was just working with an earlier version of similar ideas.

Comment: In the Elephant, a truncated version of Segal's approach is taken to defining internal categories (Def B 2.3.1). So the object of composable pairs is part of the data.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thank you for the explanation, I've never really worked with any simplical stuff but it might be time to invest.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Nice, so we have some extra work defining the internal category itself but that takes the work out of some proofs, thank you for explaining.

Comment: @TimCampion So we would specify a chosen pullback as the object of composable pairs, then form composable triplets using a pullback with the chosen object of arrows? I like this, but wouldn't we still have a coordinate-switching isomorphism to work with?

Comment: @AlecRhea Yes, there will still be such isomorphisms involved when working with composable triples. More generally, one could truncate a Segal-type description of internal categories at any point, or just straight-up work with Segal objects (which are equivalent to category objects, but have a canonical object of $n$-strings of composable morphisms for every $n$).